# Rigorous proof of the closure of irrational numbers are reals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

I am wondering how I can prove that the closure of irrationals are reals. It is intuitively and logically sensible since irrationals and rationals are dense everywhere; thus, taking the closure of irrationals means it is also reals containing the irrationals.
But how can I put this into a rigorous mathematical proof?

Comment: [Wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closure_of_Irrational_Numbers_is_Real_Numbers) gives a rigorous proof.

Comment: The closure of an everywhere dense set is the reals.

Comment: It is enough to show that every interval $(a, b)$ contains an irrational number. Because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R},$ there exists a rational number $q \in (a/\sqrt2, b/\sqrt2).$ Then $q\sqrt2 \in (a, b),$ and $q\sqrt2$ is irrational. (One could also argue that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and $(a, b)$ is uncountable, but I think that's unnecessarily sophisticated.)